# how can I disable my bluetooth's desire to connect to a wireless keyboard?

Tags: bluetooth

How can I get my laptop to stop wanting to connect to an external keyboard?  It's like it's fallen in love with this one time when it was connected, and now the builtin keyboard and trackpad don't work because the bluetooth is in an endless circle of trying to connect to some beloved keyboard (and trackpad, I think) that is 8 miles away.

Comment: windows, linux, osx?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't elaborate on which OS you're using, I'll assume it is some version of Windows.

What could very be happening is the BT keyboard may have included a driver you installed that has rudely overwritten/modified your native Windows Keyboard and Mouse drivers.

You should open the Registry of a similar and working system, and navigate to the `HKLM\System\CurrentcontrolSet\Services\KBDClass` and Mouseclass Keys of the working system.

Compare it to your malfunctioning system for parity.

if they seem identical, then delete the kbdclass.sys and mouseclass.sys files from your broken sytems  `%windir%\system32\drivers` directory.  Windows will automatically restore the drivers from the protected file cache and this should restore the original Microsoft drivers.

if that still fails, then return with some detailed information assuming you haven't already tried searching the web for your others with your same problem.